# print array in the log cat android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-logcat

How can I print the arr variable in the log to see the results of the array thanks,

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonone)
     {
          genrandom grandom =new genrandom();
          int[] arr=new int[50];
          arr = new  gen_random_number().genrandom(arr, yourXvalue);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I Googled this question and this helped me.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

```
Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
// or
System.out.println("arr: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Or, if your array is multidimensional, use [Arrays.deepToString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

```
String[][] x = new String[][] {
    new String[] { "foo", "bar" },
    new String[] { "bazz" }
};
Log.d("this is my deep array", "deep arr: " + Arrays.deepToString(x));
// or
System.out.println("deep arr: " + Arrays.deepToString(x));
// will output: [[foo, bar], [bazz]]
```

Comment: absolutely correct and acceptable answer.

Comment: @user1760556 `tag` can be any string you want. From the javadoc: *"Used to identify the source of a log message. It usually identifies the class or activity where the log call occurs."*

Comment: Not working for two-dimensional array.

Comment: `deepToString` is working for two-dimensional array

Answer (score 6):

Very simple use for each **loop** much fast then normal for (incremental) loop.

```
for(String log : array)
{
  Log.v("Tag",log);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for each loop

```
for(int x: arr){
Log.d(tag,"x:"+x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
for (int i =0 ;i<arr.length;i++)
{
   Log.v("Array Value","Array Value"+arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   Log.d(TAG, arr[i]);
}
```

What we are doing here is iterating over the array using the for loop to print logcat. Log cat output can be done with `Log.d(..)`, `Log.v(..)` , `Log.i(..)` or `Log.e(..)`. See more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try plain old

```
 System.out.println()
```